# My Ubuntu 14.04 LTS doesn't have sound

Tags: audio, vmware-workstation, ubuntu-14.04

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 on *VMware workstation version 10.0.0* on my Windows 7 machine. After installing I figured out that it doesn't have any sound so I checked the sound settings. All items seem to be at their default states and correct. Then I tried to connect the sound but got this message. Whatever the problem is, it's about this message,

- "*Error opening sound device1: A device ID has been used that is out
  of range for your system. Failed to connect virtual device sound*".

Any suggestion to find the problem?